# Which group came first - the Pharisees or the Sadducees - and how far back can their origins be traced?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, sadducees, tzadok-hakohen-lublin, pharisees

From what little I know, I understand that Sadducees were upper-class wealthy men, mostly from Jerusalem, who made up the Jewish aristocracy. Pharisees came from all economic classes but were distinguished by their rigid adherence to specific behavior prescriptions arising from their interpretation of the ambiguities in the Torah. I have read that after the destruction of the Second Temple by the Romans, Pharisaic beliefs became the foundational, liturgical, and ritualistic basis for Rabbinic Judaism.

With regard to “who came first”, the Pharisees claimed Mosaic authority for their interpretation of Jewish religious law, while Sadducees represented the authority of the priestly privileges and prerogatives established since the days of Solomon, when Zadok, their ancestor, officiated as high priest.

What I would like to know is who came first - the Pharisees or the Sadducees, and how far back can their origins be traced?

Edit: With regard to the Tzedukim (mentioned in comments below) I understand that they were named after its founder Tzadok. There was a Tzeduki Sanhedrin in the times of Shimon ben Shatach, but this was a different Sanhedrin, separate from the mainstream Sanhedrin.

P.S. I realise this is a dreadful time for your people and my heart goes out to you.

Comment: I’m assuming you want to know which approach to Torah interpretation came first?

Comment: Ah, not really. I'm interested in the historical, linear progression of events that led to the emergence of both parties. I'm not Jewish but I want to learn more about the development of Judaism up to the destruction of the temple by the Romans.  Is my question "legitimate" within the confines of Mi Yodeya? I do hope so.

Comment: According to the Pharisees the Sadducees are a rebellious offshoot of the Pharisees. We don't have much information on Sadducee sources so who knows what their account is.

Comment: Yeah, the Tzedukim don’t exist anymore, so it’s hard to get firsthand accounts. The Karaites are about the closest you’ll get, but they’re younger than Rabbinic Judaism.

Comment: @Harel13 - If the Sadducees are a rebellious offshoot of the Pharisees, then does that mean the Pharisees came first?  And do they claim their origins from Moses?

Comment: @ezra - I've read a little about the Karaites, but didn't the Sadducees claim their origins from Zadok the priest? Surely, there must be some information in Jewish writings?

Comment: The Pharisees SAY the Sadducees split away from the Pharisaic tradition, but why would you trust the Pharisees to relay Sadduceean history? And no, Jewish writings don’t bother to discuss Sadducees at length.

Comment: @Lesley it means that the Pharisees *say* they came first.

Answer (score 1):

My appreciation to Ezra and Harel13 for their comments with regard to the difficulties in determining the history of the Pharisees and the Sadducees.  I have searched on-line for additional information and found a helpful (albeit simplistic) article that gives an overview of the Pharisees, Sadducees, and Essenes, who emerged under Hasmonean rule.  Part of it says this:

> The most important of the three were the Pharisees because they are the spiritual fathers of modern Judaism.  Their main distinguishing characteristic was a belief in an Oral Law that God gave to Moses at Sinai along with the Torah.  The Pharisees believed that God also gave Moses the knowledge of what these laws meant and how they should be applied. This oral tradition was codified and written down roughly three centuries later in what is known as the Talmud.

> The Sadducees were elitists who wanted to maintain the priestly caste, but they were also liberal in their willingness to incorporate Hellenism into their lives, something the Pharisees opposed. The Sadducees rejected the idea of the Oral Law and insisted on a literal interpretation of the Written Law; consequently, they did not believe in an afterlife, since it is not mentioned in the Torah. The focus of Sadducee life was rituals associated with the Temple.

> The Sadducees disappeared around 70 A.D., after the destruction of the Second Temple. None of the writings of the Sadducees has survived, so the little we know about them comes from their Pharisaic opponents.  These two “parties” served in the Great Sanhedrin, a kind of Jewish Supreme Court made up of 71 members whose responsibility was to interpret civil and religious laws.

Source: https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/pharisees-sadducees-and-essenes